# making fadeIn and fadeOut effect work smootly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where my image will fade in and fadeout effects are there.. The fadein option seems to be some issue as it happens immediatley... Please find my jsfiddle.

Please help

Comment: You're giving us quite a challenge there - find your non-reference jsfiddle!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/he4an/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things, first `fadeIn()` only runs on hidden elements so you need to hide your images initially, second you need to wait for the `fadeOut()` animation to complete before animating the next image. This code should work for you, I removed the interval and the count variable:

```
var $slideshowImgs = $('.slideshow img').hide();
(function fadeSlideshow ($img){
    var $next = $img.next();
    if(!$next.length)
        $next = $slideshowImgs.first();
    $img.delay(2000).fadeOut(function(){
        $next.fadeIn();
        fadeSlideshow($next);
    });
})($slideshowImgs.first().show());
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/he4an/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

check this js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/TXrDk/2/

use

```
transition:.5s ease-in-out;
```